# What should our FAQ contain?

Tags: discussion, faq, scope

As you all know there has been some discussion regarding what the scope of our site should be, therefore we would like your opinion on what our FAQ should contain.

I've posted the draft several users and I have composed, but there are problems that need to be fleshed out:

- It needs to be more unambiguous, so "such as food safety" is too vague.
- The length may be a bit overkill, so if we can merge items into one that would be great
- The wording isn't always optimal, so if you suggestions, leave a comment and/or fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What kind of questions can I ask here?

Fitness - Stack Exchange is for fitness professionals, athletes and trainers. If you have a question about …

- improving your exercise performance or technique
- choosing a training program
- nutrition as it relates to exercise
- gear and gadgets used during exercise
- achieving physique milestones
- injury prevention

and it is **not about** …

- the rules of a sport
- a purchase recommendation
- general weight loss advice
- nutrition unrelated to exercise, such as food safety, nutritional needs for children, etc.
- trainer certification -- it’s for professionals, but not about the profession
- wellness, general health, medical advice and injuries unrelated to exercise

… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!
Please [look around](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/search) to see if your question has been asked before. It’s also OK to [ask and answer your own question.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: [Here's a link to the original Google Docs version, which included some of the comments from other users](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Eol0hrB-Wdl7NZoBn_CrCkM8wPY-0eyAFZKpVSpfDPA/edit)

Comment: Tweaked the last section slightly to consolidate and re-arrange. General theme (questions related to exercise) seems to be shining through - might be able to trim further.

Comment: @Shog9 Most points from the *not about* are based on actual questions we've gotten or related Area51 proposals. Perhaps not all points are needed, but can be implied from what it should be about. Such as the trainer certification, rules of a sport or purchase recommendation. Though the length is rather balanced right now. Still thanks for the edit

Comment: Ivo, you should probably push this into the actual FAQ now. I think it's had all the baking it needs - if anyone has feedback in the future, you can always update it later...