# Fitness and Nutrition is now Physical Fitness

Tags: discussion

There's been much discussion about the name of this site (most recently [here](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/q/287/2282)) and at the end of it all we have decided to go ahead and rename Fitness & Nutrition to ... **drumroll** ... **Physical Fitness**!

Don't stop doing what you're doing  - adjusting the site's scope, improving overall quality, and encouraging fitness-related questions that have been working well here.

As [Robert said](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/a/295/2282),

> This isn't a silver bullet. There's still a lot of work needed to shore up the quality of the content here. But it emphasizes and reestablished the strength of what seems to be working here from that which, frankly, doesn't.

The domain will remain the same, but you should see the new name appear in logos and whatnot shortly. Enjoy. :)

Comment: I am glad to know that you guys finally managed to drop the hilarious "Nutrition" on your banner, although I think it should be done earlier.